# Making a jQuery cycle plugin become responsive to the layout pixels?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

This is my markup for a slideshow. As you can see in my stylesheet I am specifying the slideshow's height explicitly, but I would really like to avoid this, so that when I make the browser larger or smaller the slideshow size changes as well.

```
<section class="contentSlider">
    <section class="contentSliderControls">
        <a href="#" class="controlPrev">Prev</a>
        <a href="#" class="controlNext">Next</a>
        <ul class="controlSlides"></ul>
    </section>
    <ul class="slides">
        <li><img class="sliderImage" src="/images/sliderContent_1.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img class="sliderImage" src="/images/sliderContent_1.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img class="sliderImage" src="/images/sliderContent_1.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img class="sliderImage" src="/images/sliderContent_1.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img class="sliderImage" src="/images/sliderContent_1.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img class="sliderImage" src="/images/sliderContent_1.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img class="sliderImage" src="/images/sliderContent_1.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img class="sliderImage" src="/images/sliderContent_1.png" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
```

This is my javascript

```
$(function() {
    $('.slides').cycle({
        fx:      'scrollHorz',
        timeout:  0,
        prev:    '.contentSliderControls > .controlPrev',
        next:    '.contentSliderControls > .controlNext',
        pager:   '.contentSliderControls > .controlSlides',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: pagerFactory
    });

function pagerFactory(idx, slide) {
    return '<li><a href="#">'+(idx+1)+'</a></li>';
    };
});
```

and my css

```
/* Content Slider */

.contentSlider {
position: relative;
}

.contentSlider, .contentSlider > .slides {
height: 504px;
}

.controlSlides > li {
float: left;
}

.contentSlider > .slides {
z-index: 1;
}

.sliderImage {
width: 100%;
}

.contentSliderControls {
height: 504px;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
z-index: 2;
}

.contentSliderControls > .controlPrev {
background-color: #ffffff;
color: #000000;
display: block;
float:left;
height: 504px;
opacity: .5;
width: 10%;
}

.contentSliderControls > .controlNext {
background-color: #ffffff;
color: #000000;
display: block;
float:right;
height: 504px;
opacity: .5;
width: 10%;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you fix this sentence?:  _"I would really like not to have a height or the on slide show."_  It makes no sense and I have no idea what you're trying to say.

Comment: Try this http://www.bluebit.co.uk/blog/Using_jQuery_Cycle_in_a_Responsive_Layout

Answer (score 8):

I've solved this problem like this:

```
var activeSlide;

$(document).ready(function() {

$('.cycle').cycle({
    containerResize: 1,
    width: 'fit',
    after: function(curr, next, obj) {
        activeSlide = obj.currSlide;
    }
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.cycle').cycle('destroy');
    $('.cycle').each(function(){
        newWidth = $(this).parent('div').width();
        $(this).width(newWidth);
        $(this).height('auto');
        $(this).children('div').width(newWidth);
        $(this).children('div').height('auto');
    });
    $('.cycle').cycle({
        containerResize: 1,
        width: 'fit',
        after: function(curr, next, obj) {
            activeSlide = obj.currSlide;
        },
        startingSlide: activeSlide
    });
});

});
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$('.slides').cycle({
    fx:      'scrollHorz',
    timeout:  0,
    prev:    '.contentSliderControls > .controlPrev',
    next:    '.contentSliderControls > .controlNext',
    pager:   '.contentSliderControls > .controlSlides',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: pagerFactory,
    slideResize: true,
    containerResize: false,
    width: '100%',
    fit: 1
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to set max-width: 100% as well for your .sliderImage class. That should fix the problem.
Keep in mind that you need big enough image and that the height of the cycle container is still fixed value.

Here's your example with max-width: 100% css attribute added:
http://jsfiddle.net/vfonic/YH5je/

Comment: That helps - however it doesn't work when the window is resized as JQuery Cycle adds a fixed height and width to the image as an inline style.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a dummy image with your max width, like this:

http://www.bluebit.co.uk/blog/Using_jQuery_Cycle_in_a_Responsive_Layout

Here's an example:

http://dev.bluebit.co.uk/mark/cycle/index-basic.html

I guess someone already told you this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use new version JQuery Cycle plugin v.2

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/

It supports responsive by default.