# Finger swipe gallery control - resize issue

Tags: iphone, jquery-plugins, swipe

I'm using a jQuery finger swipe plugin to show a photo gallery on mobile.  The gallery container is set to 100% width and when the page loads it fills the screen fine.  However, when the screen is rotated, the gallery container does not re-size.

I've added a re-size detect event that re-sizes the gallery container on screen rotate, and the 1st slide re-sizes fine, but the remaining slides are not re-sized.  I added a class to all of the hidden slides and updated them as well, but the plugin appears to be ignoring those sizes.  It looks like it detects the width on page load, and ignores any changes I make to the width's on re-size.

Any ideas on how to tackle this?  The plugin name is "jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library" and I'm using it exactly as described here: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Touchwipe-iPhone-iPad-wipe-gesture

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this issue was not with the finger swipe plugin, but the Cycle plugin.  There are several options for making the Cycle plugin responsive, but the one that worked for me can be found here:
[Making a jQuery cycle plugin become responsive to the layout pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003290/making-a-jquery-cycle-plugin-become-responsive-to-the-layout-pixels)